# Yii подменить dataProvider?

Tags: php, yii

Хочу вывести в TbExtendedGridView свои данные из представления.
Предположим я подменю 'dataProvider' => $model->mysearch(),
Но вот как подключиться к другой таблице? как ему другой tableName передать? или же другую модель сделать и оттуда dataProvider получать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно подключить другую модель

```
$newModel = new Lvl;
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id' => 'quality-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $newModel->search(),
```